# How to pass a value to the method?

Tags: java, class, enums, constants

In the  code below I am hard coding `USER_AND_ADMIN`:

```
this.contentUrl.getUtils().createType(url, user, content,USER_AND_ADMIN);
```

`USER_AND_ADMIN` will change depending on the scenario; the other types I may need to pass are `USER`, `ADMIN`, and `NONE`.

Could someone help with this?

Comment: Are you passing in `enum` values?

Comment: No. i am not passing

Comment: What do you need to do with this code? When and why can the value change?

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum like this

```
public enum UserType {
    USER_AND_ADMIN, USER, ADMIN, NONE;
}
```

then use it in the method declaration:

```
... methodName(... , UserType userType, ...) { ...
```

When calling the method, you just need to do this:

```
this.contentUrl.getUtils().createType(url, user, content, UserType.USER_AND_ADMIN);
```

In the method, then you can get the `String` representation, by using the `#name()` method:

```
String userTypeAsString = userType.name();
```

By default the String representation is the same as the name of the variable, so if you do not define your own `#toString()`, it does exactly the same as `#name()`. If you need to have a custom representation, write your own `#toString()`, and use it instead of `#name()`.

I prefer using `#name()` whenever applicable, as you can be sure it is not overridden -- because it is a `final` method of `Enum`.

**Update:**

If you really do not want to use `enum`s (though why is beyond me), you can use normal String constants:

```
private static final String USER_AND_ADMIN = "USER_AND_ADMIN";
```

Then you branch on the values:

```
if (userType.equals(USER_AND_ADMIN)) {
    ....
}
```

Or if you are using Java 7 or newer:

```
switch (userType) {
    case USER_AND_ADMIN:
        // ...
        break;
    case NONE:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

If you are using `enum`s, the switch works below Java 7 too.

Comment: Could you suggest me another way, i mean not enums

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ENUMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Like first create an enum

```
public enum MyEnumValues{
      USER_AND_ADMIN,
      USER,
      ADMIN,
      NONE
}
```

Then make your conditional code work based on enums :

```
MyEnumValues resultScenario = MyEnumValues.NONE;
if(scenaio1)
{
       resultScenario = MyEnumValues.USER_AND_ADMIN;
}else if(scenario2)
       resultScenario = MyEnumValues.USER;
}

//use and pass it to your method (you might have to change your method signature):
this.contentUrl.getUtils().createType(url, user, content,resultScenario );
```